# How to query Organizational Units from a given DN in Perl

Tags: perl, ldap, ou, netldap

I need to retrieve all Organizational Units from a given DN stringh, I am using Net::LDAP module and this little script:

```
my $msg = $ldap->search(
    base=>'DC=sample1,DC=sample2',
    filter=>'(objectclass=User)',
);
foreach $entry ($msg->entries) {
    $dn = $entry->dn;
    #how can i retrieve OUs?
}
```

For example if dn returns that string:

> CN=Sample Sample,OU=One,OU=Two,DC=sample1,DC=sample2

I want to retrieve One and Two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue a one level search request using the base object `dc=example1,dc=sample2` and a presence filter of `(ou=*)`. Given those results, issue a one level search using each returned `ou` with a presence filter of `(ou=*)`. For each of these searches, specify a size limit and a time limit. For more information on search requests, see ["LDAP: Using ldapsearch"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/) and ["LDAP: programming practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/).

Comment: What do you mean with "one level search"? Sorry but it's my first time with LDAP queries. Is there a way I can retrieve those values starting from the search I did?

Comment: A "one level search" restricts the search to the immediate subordinates of an entry. For example, a one-level search at dc=sample1,dc=sample2 would return just the entries immediately below dc=sample1,dc=sample2, such as ou=two in your example. LDAP has three 'scopes', 'base' (the entry itself), 'one' (as stated, immediate subordinates), and 'sub' (all entries below the target and the target itself). A search with a scope of 'one' at dc=example1,dc=example2 would return ou=two and all other entries at that level, but none below that level. The code could then iterate through those.

Answer (score 0):

Most detailed "(&(ou=*)(objectClass=organizationalunit))"

Comment: The question is seeking some `perl` code that will retrieve OUs. At the time of adding this comment, it does not seem to offer that answer. Consider [edit]ing your answer to provide more detail of what you mean.